openlitespeed server configuration for wordpress has low resource usage even with apache benchmarking tool
I have an openlitespeed server configuration for wordpress site. I am trying to simulate many user behaviour with ab but whatever I do it doesnt go over 1.5gigs of ram or %45 cpu utilization. What should I do to get use much of the 32gigs of ram avaliable and %100 cpu utilization?
Thanks in advance.

Check JMeter, create simple test with a lot of threads and try.

Please edit you question to add much more:  the ab command line in particular options -c and -n,  the configuration of httpd and php-fpm (and mysql if on the same host), your operating system distro and version, and the  ab results in particular  Requests per second   and  Concurrency Level.   As your question is now, we have no idea how many requests are coming in, the number of workers, or what tools to examine performance in detail.
